# How do I get my EOS M to release the shutter with an adapted manual lens?

Tags: canon, old-lenses, lens-adapter, canon-m

I have a Canon FD-mount lens and a Nikon pre-AI lens, with respective adapters.

I attach the FD lens to my EOS M, set the camera to M or Av mode, and the aperture is fixed at 00. When I press the shutter button, it doesn't fire.

How do I use these vintage lens on an EOS M?

Answer (score 17):

In Custom function menu:
C.Fn-7
Release shutter without lense: on

The shutter can release.

It can shoot in either mode, including P, AV, TV, M.
In TV mode, set ISO to auto. ISO becomes a variable according to time and aperture you set.

Comment: This was very helpful. One side note. You must have not NOT set on green "a" setting (at shutter button) otherwise you wont see "custom settings (c.fn) -

Comment: Thanks guys! Have a boatload of old fd series lenses which work very well on this camera.