# Canon EOS M not recording

Tags: lens, canon

My canon EOS M doesn't want to record or take any pictures. I press the record button and nothing happens. Also, when I go to adjust the aperture it says I can't because it says "no lens attatched. Is that why it doesn't let me record? What can I do

Comment: What lens are you using?

Answer (score 1):

If you are using an adapted lens, the camera may not register its presence, but of course it still works. You can change a setting in the camera to allow it to shoot without a lens attached (also without a memory card, if you like).

The following link should be helpful:

[How do I get my EOS M to release the shutter with an adapted manual lens?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/39557/how-do-i-get-my-eos-m-to-release-the-shutter-with-an-adapted-manual-lens)

If you think your lens should be "attached" (according to the camera), it's possible the electrical contacts need to be cleaned (gently) or that the lens is not attached properly (take it off and carefully re-attach it and see if that helps?)