# My Canon EOS M does not take a photo when I press the button with 7Artisans lens

Tags: canon-m

I have an old Canon EOS M, the original, with a 7Artisans manual lens, no electronics.

When I press the shutter release button is does nothing. It used to work before my kids borrowed it! Video is fine.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I get my EOS M to release the shutter with an adapted manual lens?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/39557/how-do-i-get-my-eos-m-to-release-the-shutter-with-an-adapted-manual-lens) While you're not adapting a manual lens, the Artisans are also manual electronically communication with the camera: your camera needs to be set to shoot without sensing a lens on the mount.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- In photo taking mode, press the INFO button until the white screen comes up and make sure you're on M for Manual Exposure. Touch M in top left and a second screen will present options M, Av, Tv, P. Touch M again.
- Press INFO to exit.
- Now the MENU options will contain far more options to change!
- Under maybe the 4th spanner, find Custom Functions
- Press SET to enter that bit and use left/right to find "Release shutter w/o len" and enable it.
- Hit MENU until you're back out.
- Take a photo!

Comment: @inkista Doesn't the camera have to be in Manual exposure mode to be able to get to that menu option?